# Orchestrate Cloud Formation using Code Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I'm using Code Pipeline: Jenkins for Build and Code Deploy/Opsworks for deployment.
I am able to Orchestrate Cloud Formation template with AWS CLI using Jenkins, specifying a Command line step.
Is there any other option Orchestrate Cloud Formation without using Jenkins or any CI tool? Once the build is done, can it trigger the Cloud Formation in Code pipeline?

Please suggest any best practices.

Answer (score 3):

AWS CloudFormation stack updates are now fully integrated into AWS CodePipeline as of [Nov 3 2016](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/11/continuously-deliver-changes-to-aws-cloudformation-stacks-with-aws-codepipeline/). See the newly-added section of the CloudFormation User Guide, [Continuous Delivery with AWS CodePipeline](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline.html).

In short, you can now add a `Deploy` action with a `CloudFormation` provider to your CodePipeline pipeline that will perform actions on the specified CloudFormation stack. Using the `AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline` resource, the pipeline stage definition will look something like this:

```
Resources:
  Pipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      # [other properties...]
      Stages:
      # [other stages...]
      - Name: Deploy
        Actions:
        - Name: Deploy
          ActionTypeId:
            Category: Deploy
            Owner: AWS
            Version: 1
            Provider: CloudFormation
          InputArtifacts:
          - Name: Template
          Configuration:
            ActionMode: REPLACE_ON_FAILURE
            RoleArn: !GetAtt [CFNRole, Arn]
            StackName: !Ref AWS::StackName
            TemplatePath: !Sub "Template::${StackFileName}"
            Capabilities: CAPABILITY_IAM
```